# Implementing select/3 in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm new to Prolog and came across this predicate, `select/3`. I figured how it works though I'm uncertain how I would implement it myself. I think something like:

```
selec(El,[El|T],T).
selec(El,[H|T],[H|S]) :-
      selec(El,T,S).
select(El,[],[]).
```

I know something is wrong. My solution only removes the first occurrence. I want it to remove, all occurrences at some point, just like `select/3` does.
Any ideas?

Comment: For fun, if you type `listing(select/3).` at the `?-` prompt, Prolog will show you how it is implemented. :) Some built-ins will show up as "foreign" but most things (including `select/3` and `member/2`) are not.

Comment: Take a step back and see the bigger picture! No need to rush into writing your own implementation as long as you don't know the precise meaning of `select/3`. I'd start out by writing (positive as well as negative) assertions for `select/3`. Use different terms, not just `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, but also lists containing non-integer elements `[a,b,a,d,c,a,f,e]` and lists containing shared variables like `A,B,C,B,C,A]`.

Comment: @repeat I already tested it to see what it does, before posting

Comment: In your question you stated: *"I want it to remove, all occurrences at some point, just like `select/3` does."* No. `select/3` does not do what you imply it does. In fact, whenever `select(E,Xs,Ys)` holds true, then `same_length([E|Ys],Xs)` **must** also be true! Consider the answers to the query `?- select(X,[1,1,1,1,1],Xs).`...

Comment: I understand what you say. I just don't know how to express myself. I also understand what select/3 does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine, except you don't need the `select(El,[],[]).` predicate.

This is all you need:

```
selec(El,[El|T],T).
selec(El,[H|T],[H|S]) :-
      selec(El,T,S).
```

Do keep in mind that the standard prolog parameter order is inputs followed by outputs, so you really should write it like this:

```
selec([El|T],El,T).
selec([H|T],El,[H|S]) :-
      selec(T,El,S).
```